# How to parse a dictionary items in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I have below file

`file.py`

```
data = {
    "SerialNumber": 1234,
    "ActualCount": "TY"
}
```

In `app.py` I can easily import this file and can call the dictionary like below:

`app.py`

```
import file as file

print(file.data['SerialNumber'])
```

Is there any type of parser available which can parse this dict objects and then we can get its items like below:

```
print(file.data.SerialNumber)
print(file.data.ActualCount)
```

Comment: And why not `file.data['SerialNumber']`? What's the difference between this and `file.data.SerialNumber` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, you can implement your own dict class supporting `__getattribute__` method, rough example:

```
data = {
    "SerialNumber": 1234,
    "ActualCount": "TY"
}


class MyDict(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return self[item]


my_dict = MyDict(data)

print(my_dict.SerialNumber) # 1234
```

Comment: [__getattr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) is probably more appropriate?, or maybe check if it's not in the __dict__ instance, then look the attribute up in the old way as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you need this behavior you can also try `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

data = {"SerialNumber": 1234, "ActualCount": "TY"}

MyDict = namedtuple('MyDict', data.keys())
my_dict = MyDict(**data)

print(my_dict.SerialNumber)  # 1234
print(my_dict.ActualCount)  # TY
```